# IPtables exception on block facebook access

Tags: linux, iptables, slackware

I have 3 ip ranges on my network, I blocked Facebook access with the command line:

iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "facebook.com" -j DROP

I would like to make an exception to the network range "192.168.0.x"

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `negate` the source IP address using the `!` mark.

```
iptables -I FORWARD ! -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m string --algo bm --string "facebook.com" -j DROP
```

Comment: Check all your forward rules, make sure you don't have another forward rules which blocks all. Or flush all the rules and then add the rule I posted.